# Angular filter by text input and checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ng repeat that I'm successfully filtering by an input. I also have 3 checkboxes relating to the data that I want to be able to use to filter out certain results. I've tried putting all the fields in an array (in the same manner that you'd orderBy) but this doesn't appear to help.

How can I achieve my desired result?

My template looks like:

```
<input ng-model="searchByName.name" type="text" placeholder="Search by name" autofocus>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-toggle">
       ATM
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="hasATM.atm">
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
       Power
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="hasPower.power">
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
       Water
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="hasWater.water">
    </li>
</ul>


<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="harbour in harbours | filter:[searchByName, hasATM, hasPower, hasWater] | orderBy:[sortOption, 'distance']" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/harbours/{{harbour.id}}">
        <h2>{{harbour.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And my data is in the format of:

```
"harbours": [
        {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lorem",
        "latitude": 51.000000,
        "longitude": 0.000000,
        "mooring": 3,
        "swimming": 2,
        "shopping": 4,
        "dining": 5,
        "nightlfe": 3,
        "noise": 1,
        "water": 0,
        "power": 0,
        "atm": 1,
        "distance": 0,
        "description": "lorem ipsum",
        "image":"tmp.jpg"
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ipsum",
        "latitude": 52.00000,
        "longitude": 0.00000,
        "mooring": 3,
        "swimming": 4,
        "shopping": 4,
        "dining": 5,
        "nightlfe": 1,
        "noise": 5,
        "water": 0,
        "power": 0,
        "atm": 1,
        "distance": 0,
        "description": ""
      }
]
```

Using just "searchByName" as my filter (not in the array) works great but when I try and use any of the checkboxes by themselves, the datalist just disappears.

"searchByName" when used in the array makes the list disappear too so I'm assuming this can't be achieved as simply as I'd hoped.

How can I achieve the search by name and checkbox filtering?

Thank you

Comment: create a custom filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that it's much easier to store all your filters in one object (For example, I'll use `yourFilter` variable in the example). With this approach you can just pass your variable to `filter`.

The next issue here, that your checkboxes store `false` or `true` value, because `value` tag, which you applied to them, doesn't have any effect. And if you choose one of the checkboxes, any result won't be found, because all your boolean fields has `0` or `1` value. 
To change format of stored value of the checkboxes you should refactor them with `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`, so that they can be used to filter your data.

After that your template with search inputs will look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourFilter.name" placeholder="Search by name"/>
<ul>
  <li>
   ATM
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourFilter.atm" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"/>
  </li>
  <li>
   Power
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourFilter.power" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"/>
  </li>
  <li>
   Water
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourFilter.water" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"/>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="harbour in harbours | filter:yourFilter">
    <h2>{{harbour.name}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Example on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dp3JLvfkfimwyFPBamdx?p=preview)

[Documentation about input[checkbox].](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

---

Remember, that after loading the page the checkboxes don't have any effect on filtered results. And if you want to filter by their default value, you should use `ng-init` directive.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourFilter.water" ng-init="yourFilter.water = '0'" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"/>
```

Comment: Too easy :) You're a genius. Thanks!

Comment: On the same topic. Is there anyway to have the false value be a wildcard so when you uncheck the checkbox you get the atm/power/water values matching 1 OR 0?

Comment: @Fraser, to be honest, I don't know. And maybe it's a little bit tricky, it'll be better to create a custom filter to filter data in this way. Or you can move this logic to a function in your controller. In this function you can format your filter object in any way. I've created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0wfv4aD5gkEt4QWvx6y?p=preview). Have a look at `formatFilterInANiceWay` function which is used to format required object for `filter` and you can use it in this way: `<li ng-repeat="harbour in harbours | filter: ctrl.formatFilterInANiceWay(yourFilter)">`.

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/thrZmKX40Ll75VFLu8z4?p=preview) is an example with custom filter. It should be refactored, but I hope that you'll get the idea.